# mail can be send and received from outside network but mail (outlook or webamil ) not accessible from local network

Tags: domain-name-system, email, port, forwarding, mikrotik

my private block is 192.168.109.0/24
WAN is 82.198.x.x. and mail server is on 192.168.109.x.
I have made the rules dst-nat for port 25,587,993 and 143 with destination 82.198.x.x forwarded to the mail server ip.
I have  a internal dns server which is resolved from local network.
however, I cant access to mail server and showing smtp not reachable though from outside of network am accessing the mail.

What could be the issue

Comment: We do need more details in order for us to help. Show the configurations, the logs, the software being used, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you are connecting, are you connecting to the servers IP-address on your LAN or are you using the domain name (i.e. mail.example.com)? On your LAN; what IP-address do your DNS-record for your mail-server resolve to?